# I've accidentally installed a different Greeter. How can I get Pantheon Greeter back?

Tags: greeter

I have weird purple login screen, I don't know why.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've somehow installed the Ubuntu Unity greeter. This may have been pulled in when you installed something else Ubuntu or Unity-related. Remember to be very careful when copying commands from the Internet and to pay close attention to what packages might be installed or removed when you do.

You should be able to get the normal greeter back by removing `unity-greeter` and re-installing `pantheon-greeter`